# Cannot find namespace System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#

I'm wanting to use the inbuilt charting thats with .net 4.  I have an existing MVC3 application, but I cannot seem to see the reference for this namespace?

Anybody know where it is?

Thanks,

Darren.

Comment: That is not designed for MVC.

Comment: Have you looked in System.Web.DataVisualization.dll?

Comment: @SLaks, will this not work for MVC?

Comment: I don't think it will (at least, not easily)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe it's in the [System.Web.DataVisualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.datavisualization.charting.chartelement.aspx) DLL.

Answer (score 4):

Add `System.Web.UI.DataVisualization` as Assembly reference to your project.

And after you will be able to declare the namespace:

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

Answer (score 1):

Add System.Web.DataVisualization as Assembly reference. (Was located in the .net Tab.)
Add the following using statement

```
using Charting = System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

From there you will reference your charting pieces like so

```
Charting.Chart myNewChart = new Charting.Chart();
```

It will help keep your namespace a bit cleaner and probably avoid some collisions as the lexicon surrounding the graphing world is not very unique.